# When to make a django app, rather than just a model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Recently I've been making a few test projects in Django and while I've found the structure to be better than that of other Web Frameworks, I am a little confused on the concept of different 'apps'.

Here is a test case example:

Suppose I have a simple CRUD application where users post a picture and a title, with a small description, but I want other users to have the ability to create a review of this picture.

Seeing as both the "Post" and "Review" models in this case require CRUD functionality, would I just have two models in the same app, and associate them with one another? Or have two separate apps with different urls.py and views.py files?

I have a hunch I've been doing it wrong and it should be just two models, if this is the case how would I go about writing the urls and views for two models in the same app?

Thanks and any input is appreciated!

Comment: It's fairly arbitrary when you should split an app into multiple apps. Apps are mostly a way to organize your code, and while some concepts may help with that (e.g. "an app provides some set of features"), there's no clear-cut line when something must be one app or not. You'll have to figure out what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

> The term application describes a Python package that provides some
>   **set of features**. Applications may be reused in various projects.

So in this case, better to have both `Post` and `Review` as two models in one app, since both of them apply to pictures.

*how would I go about writing the urls and views for two models in the same app*

The Django project provides a near perfect documentation on how to structure [urls](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_urls/) and [views](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj5sczPjrrNAhVCtBoKHUf3Dw8QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.djangoproject.com%2Fen%2F1.9%2Ftopics%2Fhttp%2Fviews%2F&usg=AFQjCNHedejl5NMmXwhwCEEUHJXpFacugQ&sig2=8P8TMFK4kiYpj-6mh4yspg&bvm=bv.124817099,d.d2s).

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think the better is to put your two models in one app.